# How do I get public user information from the Mastodon API?

Tags: mastodon

I see a user like https://mastodon.lol/@rosinmas and according to the docs, the API endpoint should be: https://mastodon.lol/api/v1/accounts/@rosinmas

But I get:

```
{"error":"Record not found"}
```

How come the use endpoint isn't public?

Comment: Why not ask this whoever maintains that API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get account information in JSON (no authentication needed) by calling the API with the following format:

```
https://[server_name]/api/v1/accounts/[account_id]
```

For example:

```
https://mastodon.social/api/v1/accounts/1
```

will give you:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "username": "Gargron",
  "acct": "Gargron",
  "display_name": "Eugen Rochko",
  "locked": false,
  "bot": false,
  "discoverable": true,
  "group": false,
  "created_at": "2016-03-16T00:00:00.000Z",
  "note": "<p>Founder, CEO and lead developer <span class=\"h-card\"><a href=\"https://mastodon.social/@Mastodon\" class=\"u-url mention\">@<span>Mastodon</span></a></span>, Germany.</p>",
  "url": "https://mastodon.social/@Gargron",
  "avatar": "https://files.mastodon.social/accounts/avatars/000/000/001/original/dc4286ceb8fab734.jpg",
  "avatar_static": "https://files.mastodon.social/accounts/avatars/000/000/001/original/dc4286ceb8fab734.jpg",
  "header": "https://files.mastodon.social/accounts/headers/000/000/001/original/3b91c9965d00888b.jpeg",
  "header_static": "https://files.mastodon.social/accounts/headers/000/000/001/original/3b91c9965d00888b.jpeg",
  "followers_count": 222337,
  "following_count": 326,
  "statuses_count": 72729,
  "last_status_at": "2022-11-18",
  "noindex": false,
  "emojis": [],
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "Patreon",
      "value": "<a href=\"https://www.patreon.com/mastodon\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow noopener noreferrer me\"><span class=\"invisible\">https://www.</span><span class=\"\">patreon.com/mastodon</span><span class=\"invisible\"></span></a>",
      "verified_at": null
    }
  ]
}
```

To get the `account_id` for a given `username` you can pass the following API call:

```
https://[server_name]/api/v2/search?q=[username]
```

For example:

```
https://mastodon.social/api/v2/search?q=Gargron
```

will give you saturated details about all the usernames with Gargron on that server...